# how to force all kubernetes services (proxy, kublet, apiserver..., containers) to write logs to /var/logs

Tags: kubernetes, logging, syslog

How to force all kubernetes services (proxy, kublet, apiserver..., containers) to write logs to `/var/logs`?

For example:

```
/var/logs/apiServer.log
```

or:

```
/var/logs/proxy.log
```

Can I use `syslog` config to do that? What would be an example of that config?

I have already tried `journald` configuration `forward to syslogs=yes`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just first what comes to my mind - create sidecar container that will gather all the logs in 1 place.
2. [The Complete Guide to Kubernetes Logging](https://sematext.com/guides/kubernetes-logging/#kubernetes-logging-architecture-types-of-kubernetes-logs).

That's a pretty wide question that should be divided on few parts. Kubernets stores different types of logs in different places.

- **Kubernetes Container Logs** (out of this question, but simply `kubectl logs <podname>` + `-n`  for namespace, if its not default + `-c` for specifying container inside the pod)
- **Kubernetes Node Logs**
- **Kubernetes Cluster Logs**

---

**Kubernetes Node Logs**

> Depending on your operating system and services, there are various
> node-level logs you can collect, such as kernel logs or systemd logs.
>
> On nodes with systemd both the kubelet and container runtime write to
> journald. If systemd is not present, they write to .log files in the
> /var/log directory.
>
> You can access systemd logs with the journalctl command.

[Tutorial: Logging with journald](https://sematext.com/blog/journald-logging-tutorial/) have a huge explanation  how can you configure journalctl to gather logs. With agrregation logs tools like ELK and without them. [journald log filtering](https://sematext.com/blog/journald-logging-tutorial/#toc-journald-log-filtering-7) can simplify your life.

There are two ways of centralizing journal entries via syslog:

1. **syslog daemon acts as a journald client** (like journalctl or Logstash or Journalbeat)
2. **journald forwards messages to syslog** (via socket)

Option 1) is slower – reading from the journal is slower than reading from the socket – but captures all the fields from the journal.

Option 2) is safer (e.g. no issues with journal corruption), but the journal will only forward traditional syslog fields (like severity, hostname, message..)

Talking about `ForwardToSyslog=yes` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` --> it will write messages, in syslog format, to `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`. You can pass processing then this file to [rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/) for example. Either you can manually process logs or  move them to desired place..

---

**Kubernetes Cluster Logs**

By default, system components outside a container write files to journald, while components running in containers write to /var/log directory. However, there is the option to configure the container engine to stream logs to a preferred location.

**Kubernetes doesn’t provide a native solution for logging at cluster level**. However, there are other approaches available to you:

- Use a node-level logging agent that runs on every node
- Add a sidecar container for logging within the application pod
- Expose logs directly from the application.

---

P.S. I have **NOT** tried below approach, but it looks promising - check it and maybe it will help you in your not easiest task.

> The easiest way of setting up a node-level logging agent is to
> configure a DaemonSet to run the agent on each node

```
helm install --name st-agent \
  --set infraToken=xxxx-xxxx \
  --set containerToken=xxxx-xxxx \
  --set logsToken=xxxx-xxxx \
  --set region=US \
  stable/sematext-agent
```

> This setup will, by default, send all cluster and container logs to a
> central location for easy management and troubleshooting. With a tiny
> bit of added configuration, you can configure it to collect node-level
> logs and audit logs as well.